# Unable to set focus to textbox in dojo datagrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, double-click

I have a Dojo Datagrid with one of the columns being rendered as a textbox by a formatter function. When I click on the rendered textbox to enter some value, the cursor appears in the textbox and focus is immediately lost (i.e, the cursor disappears - typing does not produce anything). I have to click once more on the textbox for the focus to set - only then can I enter values.

Is there any way to set the focus on the first click itself?

Here is the code:

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="selectedItemsStore" class="resultsGridClass" jsid="selecteditems">
<thead>
<tr>
<th field="field1" formatter="renderTextBox" width="20%">Field 1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

And here is the formatter function:

```
function renderTextBox(value, rowIndex) {
var htmlString = "<input type='text' name= 'exp' />";
return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: wonder if this is related to http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9827 -- there's a reference in that ticket for a supported way to embed text inputs

Comment: same problem here. does someone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    dijit.byId("profileGrid").scrollToRow(rowIndex);
    dijit.byId("profileGrid").focus.setFocusIndex( rowIndex, 0 );
    dijit.byId("profileGrid").edit.setEditCell( dijit.byId("profileGrid").getCell(0), rowIndex );
},10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting editable and alwaysEditing attributes to true:

```
<th alwaysEditing="true" editable="true" field="field1" formatter="renderTextBox" width="20%" >Field 1</th>
```

Comment: You can try to repeat behavior from this test page (when Toggle dSingleClickEdit is pressed): http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_edit.html

Answer (score 0):

While creating an instance of `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid`, use the `singleClickEdit` attribute and set it as `true`.

This will set the focus on the textbox or any other widget on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

In my case below code works perfectly for the text box focus issue:

```
dojo.connect(this.floorTable,"onRowClick",this,function(row){               
    row.target.focus();             
});
```

where `this.floorTable` is a table object.